# I have added js using require js but it is not attached

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I have added javascript files in require js but it is not showing in the inspect element that my javascript files are attached and it is not working.
What should I do? I have cleared cache and folders and almost everything deleted.
All cache folders and almost everything but not working.

What should I do in this?
>

```
My require.js is in code/vendor/module folder 

    var config = {
    map: {
       '*': {
           jssor: 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min',
           jssorSlider: 'js/jssor.slider-27.5.0.min'
       }
   },
   shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
   },
};
```

Comment: your `requirejs-config.js` should be in `code/vendor/module/view/frontend`

Comment: Could you post your require-config file with path

Comment: code/vendor/module

Comment: updated the require.js file also

Comment: You should try to put your requirejs from this path : code/vendor/module/view/frontend